# Difference between "this" and"super" keywords in Java

Tags: java, keyword

What is the difference between the keywords `this` and `super`?

Both are used to access constructors of class right? Can any of you explain?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Lets consider this situation

```
class Animal {
  void eat() {
    System.out.println("animal : eat");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  void eat() {
    System.out.println("dog : eat");
  }
  void anotherEat() {
    super.eat();
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal a = new Animal();
    a.eat();
    Dog d = new Dog();
    d.eat();
    d.anotherEat();
  }
}
```

The output is going to be

```
animal : eat
dog : eat
animal : eat
```

The third line is printing "animal:eat" because we are calling `super.eat()`. If we called `this.eat()`, it would have printed as "dog:eat".

Comment: I don't find this answer confusing, though you can make the last line of the output bold or add a trailing comment to emphasize that the base class was used.

Answer (score 56):

`super` is used to access methods of the base class while `this` is used to access methods of the current class.

Extending the notion, if you write `super()`, it refers to constructor of the base class, and if you write `this()`, it refers to the constructor of the very class where you are writing this code.

Answer (score 22):

**`this` is a reference to the object typed as the current class, and `super` is a reference to the object typed as its parent class.**

In the constructor, `this()` calls a constructor defined in the current class.  `super()` calls a constructor defined in the parent class.  The constructor may be defined in any parent class, but it will refer to the one overridden closest to the current class.  Calls to other constructors in this way may only be done as the first line in a constructor.

Calling methods works the same way.  Calling `this.method()` calls a method defined in the current class where `super.method()` will call the same method as defined in the parent class.

Answer (score 11):

From your question, I take it that you are really asking about the use of `this` and `super` in constructor chaining; e.g.

```
public class A extends B {
    public A(...) {
        this(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

versus

```
public class A extends B {
    public A(...) {
        super(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

The difference is simple:

- The `this` form chains to a constructor in the current class; i.e. in the `A` class.
- The `super` form chains to a constructor in the immediate superclass; i.e. in the `B` class.

Answer (score 9):

`this` refers to a reference of the **current** class. 
`super` refers to the **parent** of the current class (which called the `super` keyword).

By doing `this`, it allows you to access methods/attributes of the current class (including its own private methods/attributes).

`super` allows you to access public/protected method/attributes of parent(base) class. You cannot see the parent's private method/attributes.

Comment: This is answer is right if you change every occurrence of 'class' into 'object'. It is for instance not possible to call 'this' from a static method within a class.

Comment: @Dave, true...I basically went on the fact that super calls the base class (since it's a derived class of a base class). Should I say base object? If so, what's the difference between class/object?

Comment: @TEG, I know it is a bit juggling with words and a lot of people use class and object as synonyms. The class is in fact the definition and may have static methods, constants and may even not have the possibility to be instantiated (abstract classes). An object can only exist at runtime and must be created with the ´new´ keyword.

Comment: @Dave, true, but if you look at literature, you will see words such as `base` and `derived` classes and not `based` and `derived` objects. Maybe the new literature distinguished the difference.

Comment: @TEG, I agree on the usage of 'base' and 'derived' classes in context of a class diagram (or technical analysis) as more informal naming for superclass and subclass respectively.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi can u tell me the diagrammatically use of super keyword , for this keyword i can think of it as a pointer. One more question is that when i use this keyword inside the System.out.println(this) it print address in encrypted form but i use super keyword in  System.out.println(super) it shows error why?

Answer (score 8):

### super() & this()

- super() - to call parent class constructor.
- this() -  to call same class constructor.

***NOTE:***

- We can use super() and this() only in constructor not anywhere else, any
  attempt to do so will lead to compile-time error.
- We have to keep either super() or this() as the first line of the
  constructor but NOT both simultaneously.

### super & this keyword

- super - to call parent class members(variables and methods).
- this - to call same class members(variables and methods).

***NOTE:*** We can use both of them anywhere in a class except static areas(static block or method), any
   attempt to do so will lead to compile-time error.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is used to access the methods and fields of the current object. For this reason, it has no meaning in static methods, for example.

`super` allows access to non-private methods and fields in the super-class, and to access constructors from within the class' constructors only.

Answer (score 3):

When writing code you generally don't want to repeat yourself.  If you have an class that can be constructed with various numbers of parameters a common solution to avoid repeating yourself is to simply call another constructor with defaults in the missing arguments.  There is only one annoying restriction to this - it must be the first line of the declared constructor.  Example:

```
MyClass()
{
   this(default1, default2);
}

MyClass(arg1, arg2)
{
   validate arguments, etc...
   note that your validation logic is only written once now
}
```

As for the `super()` constructor, again unlike `super.method()` access it must be the first line of your constructor.  After that it is very much like the `this()` constructors, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), if the class you extend has a constructor that does some of what you want then use it and then continue with constructing your object, example:

```
YourClass extends MyClass
{
   YourClass(arg1, arg2, arg3)
   {
      super(arg1, arg2) // calls MyClass(arg1, arg2)
      validate and process arg3...
   }
}
```

Additional information:

Even though you don't see it, the default no argument constructor always calls `super()` first.  Example:

```
MyClass()
{
}
```

is equivalent to

```
MyClass()
{
   super();
}
```

I see that many have mentioned using the `this` and `super` keywords on methods and variables - all good.  Just remember that constructors have unique restrictions on their usage, most notable is that they must be the very first instruction of the declared constructor and you can only use one.

Answer (score 3):

**this** keyword use to call constructor in the same class (other overloaded constructor)

*syntax*: **this** (args list); //compatible with **args list** in other constructor in the same class

**super** keyword use to call constructor in the super class.

*syntax:* super (args list); //compatible with **args list** in the constructor of the super class.

Ex:

```
public class Rect {
int x1, y1, x2, y2;

public Rect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) // 1st constructor 
{ ....//code to build a rectangle }
}

public Rect () {   // 2nd constructor
this (0,0,width,height) // call 1st constructor (because it has **4 int args**), this is another way to build a rectangle 
}


public class DrawableRect extends Rect {

public DrawableRect (int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2) {
super (a1,b1,a2,b2) // call super class constructor (Rect class) 
}
}
```