# declaring custom-view constructors

Tags: java, android, constructor, initialization, custom-view

Probably it's a Java more than an Android programming question, anyway: there are two ways to declare the 3 standard view constructors: one is using `this()` to call the next most parametrized constructor, with `null` and `0`, as I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884501/android-custom-view-constructor/2888594#2888594), and doing all the custom init in the last constructor.

The other way is calling `super()`, calling each time a function that does the init job.

Is one way more right than the other (why?), or it's just a style choice?

Comment: This is really a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023344/this-vs-super-keywords You can find the answer there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this vs super keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023344/this-vs-super-keywords)

Comment: I don't think it's very duplicative; this gets at the heart of: which path should your constructors take if there are multiple constructors in the superclass - and it's a very good question.  +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I guess that there isn't any technical involvement one can think of, at least none so important that hi-rep people would know for sure. so... I deduce it's only a style choice.