# How do I make a file's contents scanned and printed?

Tags: java

Using java, I need to make a program that asks the user which file to scan, and to do some work with the data in the file.

My program is supposed to select a file, scan the file for a specific character that the user specifies, and return with how many specific characters there are in that file.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you want to search.");
    String fileInput = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What character would you like to look for in " + fileInput + "?");

    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileInput);
    System.out.println(fileScanner);
    }
}
```

I imported io and scanner, then set up the scanner to read which file the user inputs. I print back out that file name. The last two lines are where I need help. How can I make the scanner return with the data in the file.

There is a file in my folder called data.txt and all that is written in it is "dataWord." For starters, I want the scanner to read the file and the program to display dataWord, but its not working. I am a rookie, so please work with me. Thanks.

Comment: `fileScanner.nextLine();` will get the first line of the file and return everything on that line as a `String` to loop through just do `while(fileScanner.hasNext())`

Comment: Oh ok, thats helpful. Is there a way for it to return everything in the file, just for future purposes?

Comment: Look into `Files.readAllLine(path)` it returns an `List<String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing path of file as `String` pass it as a `File`

```
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileInput));
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(fileScanner.next());
    }
    scanner.close();
    fileScanner.close();
```

If the file is an external file or not in your project, you can specify the **absolute path** of file.

If it is in classpath you can read using `ClassLoader`

```
     java.io.InputStream inputStream = this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file_path")
```

Scanner has a constructor with `InputStream`

Comment: After I put that in, the command prompt says that it can't find the file that I want it to look for. In the same folder as the JAVA and CLASS files, I have the text file, data.txt, that I am inputting in the command prompt where the fileInput is in the code. Do I need to specify the path of the file in a specific way because I tried M:\data.txt which is where the file is located, on my USB. What could be causing the program to not be able to locate my file?

Comment: Where do I put the java.io.InputStream thing in my code? I am very lost at this point.

Comment: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream)` hope this helps, if you face any other issues share the project structure and .classpath

Comment: So do I put the inputStream as a separate variable before all this stuff?

Comment: Also what is the "this" in the InputStream?

Comment: see my code snippet, either you can declare a variable and pass or just pass `this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file_path")` to scanner, its your wish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023344/difference-between-this-andsuper-keywords-in-java here you'll get answer

Comment: I just get a bunch of errors that say "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" and the this.getClassLoader symbol can't be found.

Comment: oh, we can't access `this` and `super` in static method, so replace `this` with `YouClass.class` i.e `CharSearch.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file_path")`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at CharSearch.main(CharSearch.java:14) Thats what the program says after i run it after compiling it.

Comment: did you try with `scanner = new Scanner(new File("M:\data.txt"))`, it'd work

Comment: I tried that out and today in class, I got the answer. Thanks for all the help.