# differences between "this" and "super" when accessing inherited members

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm new to java. Recently I saw some code which was similiar to this:

```
class A {
    protected int myInt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.myFunction();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void myFunction() {
        this.myInt = 10;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, when creating a subclass instance, an instance of its parent is created as well. All protected and public members of base class are accessible from the subclass.
If I override `myInt` there will be a difference between `this.myInt` to `super.myInt` because each class will have its own `myInt` (B will have access to both).

So, my question is: if I don't override `myInt`, which form is preferable, `this.myInt` or `super.myInt`?

Comment: You don't override fields. And a `B` is also an `A`, but only one instance is created - not two.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023344/difference-between-this-andsuper-keywords-in-java

Comment: Clarification of comment by @ElliottFrisch: If you also declare `myInt` in `B`, you're not *overriding* the field, you're *hiding* the field of same name in `A`. See [The Java™ Tutorials - Hiding Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html).

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use `this` or `super` when need to specify which scope are you using/referring to. In your case, I'll prefer to omit the `this` to simplify the readability.

`super` is used to represents the current instante of a parent class while `this` is used to represents the current class.  You only need to used this or super if some variable or method overlaps (Have the same name) with one in a wide scope.

eg. If you have define a method parameter with the same name as class attribute, you need to use this to indicate that you are using the class attribute and not the method parameter.

```
public class A {

    public int myInt = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.myFunction(3);
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public int myInt = 2;

    public void myFunction(int myInt){

        System.out.println(myInt); // The parameter
        System.out.println(this.myInt); // myInt from the current class (B)
        System.out.println(super.myInt); // myInt from the parent class (A)
    }
}
```

This example will print:

```
3
2
1
```

If you don't have this kind of collission, the use of this is optional:

```
public void myFunction2(){
    System.out.println(myInt);       // Both refers to the same 
    System.out.println(this.myInt);  // variable myInt from class B
}
```

Comment: *Opinion:* In this case, I'll prefer to use `super.` to document that an inherited field is being referenced. Similarly, I'll prefer to use `this.` on non-inherited fields to document that a field is being referenced, not a variable/parameter. It is a Code Style decision that clarifies the code to casual readers, which I find better than "simple", less clear code.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste and the project's standards/guidelines more than anything else.

Personally, I wouldn't use either, and would just write `myInt = 10`.

Comment: Thank you for qualifying your second paragraph as being your *opinion*. +1

Answer (score 0):

Only one instance is created. If you instantiate a derived object, the parents constructor is called, but only one object is created. Also, the term `this` is more so used when there are different variables with the same name being referenced in a class. 
For example a simple constructor:

```
class SupClass{
    public int a = 1;
    int incA(){
        return ++a;
    }
}
class MyClass extends SupClass {
    public int a = 10;
    public int b = 20;
    MyClass() {};
    MyClass(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    int incA(){
        return ++a;
    }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      SupClass d = new MyClass();
      System.out.println(d.a); //1, members known of type SupClass at compile-time, 
      System.out.println(d.incA()); //11, methods are virtual, decided at run-time
  }
}
```

Only use the `super` method when you want to explicitly use the value that is in the super class. To answer your question, only methods can be overwritten, member variables can not.